# zxing android qrcode generator

Tags: android

i included image of my stacktrace
[image: i included image of my stacktrace]

```
MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new 
                                       MultiFormatWriter();
    try {
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(uid, 
BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,200,200);----55
        BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
        Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap));



    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

im getting a null pointer exeption error at this point 55 .I used zxing library but im unable to perform required operation please help me

Comment: Can you include the stack-trace error you are getting?

Comment: i just included my stack trace image please just see and offer me a sugggestion

Comment: `uid` is most likely `NULL` ...while your screenshot has the relevant part cut off.

Comment: Your code doesn't include firebase code, why tagging firebase?

Comment: ill check whether uid is null or not thanks

Comment: actually im including firebase in project to do authentication ..etc but thanks 4 ur suggestion.this is new for me to be a developer

Comment: i checked  uid is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public static Bitmap encodeStringToBitmap(String contents) throws WriterException {
//Null check, just b/c
if (contents == null) {
    return null;
}
Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = new EnumMap<>(EncodeHintType.class);
hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");
MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
BitMatrix result = writer.encode(contents, BarcodeFormat.PDF_417, 700, 900, hints);
int width = result.getWidth();
int height = result.getHeight();
int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    int offset = y * width;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? 0xFF000000 : 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }
}
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
return bitmap;
}
```

For more trial

visit [Java Code Examples for com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter)

Comment: Ok. let me check